# Responsiveness Not Working on Mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have my first responsive design website [here](http://aaron.no/)

I tried resizing my window using Chrome and FF and i see that the responsiveness is working ...  But when i viewed it on my phone it looks the same as i see it in my desktop.

Here's my CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700);
html {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    font-weight: normal;
!important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.side-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.sidebar {
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    border-left: 740px solid transparent;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.main-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 60px 60px 200px 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
.postcont.main-content-wrapper, .main-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
}
::selection {
    background: #202020;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.ease {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.prettyprint {
    background-color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.profile {
    padding: 60px 20px 20px 60px;
    width: 250px;
}
.profile .avatar {
    max-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}
.profile .avatar-wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 80px 80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.profile .username {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.profile .Med.bio {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.profile .Tiny.location {
    color: #999;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.profile p {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
.profile .twitter-handle a {
    background-image: url(../images/twitter-bird-black-bgs.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-position: top left;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-size: 26px 26px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.profile .twitter-handle a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.profile .twitter-handle span {
    display: none;
}
.mini-profile {
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 -1px 0 rgb(214, 214, 214);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 -1px 0 rgb(214, 214, 214);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 -1px 0 rgb(214, 214, 214);
}
.mini-profile .avatar-wrapper, .mini-profile .avatar {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.mini-profile .avatar-wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.mini-profile .profile-about {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.mini-profile .username, .mini-profile .bio, .mini-profile .twitter-handle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.mini-profile .username {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.mini-profile .twitter-handle {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.mini-profile .location {
    display: none;
}
.mini-profile .twitter-handle a {
    background-image: url(../images/twitter-bird-light-bgs.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
.jplnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}
.jplnav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.jplnav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.jplnav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(111, 152, 190);
}
.jplnav li.active a {
    color: #CCC;
}
.section-trigger {
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.sections {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu, .expand-profile {
    width: 44px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 179);
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: #000;
}
.menu:hover, .expand-profile:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.close-menu {
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-size: 50px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wedge {
    height: 4px;
    margin: 0 8px 5px 8px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.expand-profile {
    right: 25%;
    font-family: Georgia, Roboto, "Droid Serif", serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}
.pager-footer {
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.pager {
}
.pager span, .pager a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
}
.Loading {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.Loading img {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    color: #202020;
    font-size: 52px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #FFF;
}
h1 a {
    color: inherit;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #202020;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.jplnav a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #91b6e4;
}
.jplnav li a {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.Lrg {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #202020;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.Lrg a {
    color: inherit;
}
.Med {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
.Sml {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
.Tiny {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
a {
    color: rgb(96, 167, 207);
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.post-header {
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.post-header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.post-date {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    color: #bfbfbf;
}
.entry {
    padding: 0;
}
.entry span {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
.entry img {
    max-width: 520px;
    height: auto;
}
.entry blockquote {
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
}
.entry blockquote.quote {
    border-left: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #202020;
}
.entry blockquote.quote:before {
    content: "â€œ";
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.post-footer {
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.post-origin {
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    display: block;
}
.image-block {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 10px;
}
.image-block img {
    opacity: 0;
}
.image-block a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.photo-detail {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
body.dribbble .postcont.main-content-wrapper, body.dribbble .main-content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0;
}
body.dribbble-shot .entry {
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
}
body.dribbble-shot .post-header h1 {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body.dribbble-shot .photo-detail {
/* width: 400px; */

}
body.dribbble-shot .suppliment-group {
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
body.dribbble-shot .suppliment {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
body.dribbble-shot .mini-profile {
    display: none;
}
body.flickr .postcont.main-content-wrapper, body.flickr .main-content-wrapper {
/*  margin-top:0; */

}
body.flickr-photo .main-content-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
body.flickr-photo .sidebar {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    border-left: none;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
body.flickr-photo .jplnav {
    margin-left: 90px;
}
body.flickr-photo .jplnav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 60px;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile .avatar-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile-about {
    margin-left: 90px;
    display: none;
}
body.flickr-photo .section-trigger {
    display: none;
}
body.flickr-photo .post-header {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
body.flickr-photo .breadcrumb {
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #CCC;
}
body.flickr-photo .breadcrumb a {
    color: inherit;
}
body.flickr-photo .post-header h1 {
    max-width: none;
    font-size: 38px;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    color: rgb(185, 185, 182);
    max-width: 600px;
}
body.flickr-photo .entry {
    max-width: none;
}
body.flickr-photo .entry .description {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
body.flickr-photo .photo-detail {
    text-align: center;
}
body.flickr-photo .entry img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body.flickr-photo .mini-profile {
    display: none;
}
body.flickr-photo .post-footer {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
body.flickr-photoset .post-header {
    padding: 20px 0 0 10px;
}
.video-block {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
/* hide hastags */

.ot-hashtag {
    display: none;
}
.link a {
    background-color: rgb(224, 240, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
.map {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.googleplus-post .post-footer {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
/*

* Etsy 

*/ 

body.etsy-section .post-header {
    padding: 20px 0 0 10px;
}
body.etsy-listing .post-header {
    padding: 60% 50px 0 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
body.etsy-listing .post-header h1 {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 44px;
    margin: 0;
}
body.etsy-listing .post-header p.Lrg {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1em !important;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
body.etsy-listing .photo-detail {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body.instagram-photo .mini-profile {
    display: none;
}
.postcont.achievement, .postcont.portfolio, rticle.reviews {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.postcont.achievement header, .postcont.portfolio header, .postcont.reviews header {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.angellist-grid, .angellist-grid ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.angellist-grid-content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.angellist-grid-content .angellist-company-name a:before {
    content: " / ";
 rgb(78, 78, 78);
}
.angellist-grid-content:first-child .angellist-company-name a:before {
    content: "";
}
.angellist-company-image {
    display: none;
}
.angellist-company-concept {
    display: none;
}
.angellist-grid-content:hover .angellist-company-concept {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.angellist-grid-content .angellist-company-concept {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -65px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.angellist-company-image-popup {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkist-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.angellist-company-image-popup img {
    display: none;
}
.angellist-grid-content .angellist-company-concept:after {
    top: -5px;
    right: 110px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    border-width: 0 5px 5px;
    border-color: rgb(255,255,255) transparent;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
.angellist-company-concept p.Sml {
    color: #202020;
}
.angellist-grid-content:hover .angellist-company-concept {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s, margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s, margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s, margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s, margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.github-languages {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.github-social-stats {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.github-social-stats li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.github-social-stats span.Lrg {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    display: block;
}
.portfolio .post-header h1, .github-languages .post-header h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.portfolio .post-header, .github-languages .post-header, .github-repo .post-header {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.github-repo .post-header h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.github-repo .entry p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.github-starred {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.github-starred .Lrg {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.github-main-language {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.github-main-language .Lrg {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 1em;
}
body.feed .entry h1 {
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #202020;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.feed .entry img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
body.page h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

* Responsive Styles

* * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * */





/* Large desktop */

@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* */
}



/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { /* */
}





/* Shrink Navigation */

@media (max-height: 798px) {
/*

    *

    *

    * Vertical Responsive Profile

    *

    *

    */

.profile {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.profile .avatar-wrapper {
/* display: none; */

}
/*

    *

    *

    * Vertical Responsive Site Navigation

    *

    *

    */

.jplnav a {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.jplnav {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.jplnav li {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.jplnav a {
    padding: 0;
}
}





/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.sidebar {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.main-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 60px 200px 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
.postcont.main-content-wrapper, .main-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Site Navigation

*

*

*/

.jplnav {
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
.jplnav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    text-align: left;
}
.jplnav a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Sub Navigation

*

*

*/

.section-trigger {
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 99;
}
.sections {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.section-trigger > ul.sections {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sections li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sections a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.section-block {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Image Block Styling

*

*

*/

.image-block {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 10px;
}
.image-block img {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
.image-block a {
    display: block;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Single Photo image styling

*

*

*/

.photo-detail {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
}
.photo-detail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive Pager

* 

*

*/

.pager-footer {
    margin: 25px 10px 50px 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.pager {
}
.pager span, .pager a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu, .expand-profile {
    display: block;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Generic Font Treatments

*

*

*/

.Lrg {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.Med {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.Sml {
    font-size: 18px;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: User Profile

*

*

*/

.profile {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
.profile .avatar-wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.profile .avatar {
    max-width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
.profile p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
}
.profile p.username {
    margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
    line-height: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}
.profile .Med.bio {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #d4d4d4;
}
.profile .twitter-handle a {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-size: 36px 36px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40%;
    top: 34px;
}
.profile .twitter-handle span {
    display: none;
}
.profile p.username, .profile .bio, .profile .location, .profile p {
    display: none;
}
.profile p.twitter-handle {
    display: block;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive Loading image

* 

*

*/

.Loading {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.Loading img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Post Styling

*

*

*/

.post-header {
    padding: 10% 10% 0 10%;
}
.post-header h1 {
    word-break: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.post-footer {
    padding: 0 10% 10% 10%;
}
.entry {
    padding: 0 10% 10% 10%;
}
.entry img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.entry {
}
iframe, embed, object {
    max-width: 260px;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Flickr, Dribbble Styling Overrides

*

*

*/

body.dribbble-shot .entry, body.flickr-photo .entry {
    padding: 10px;
}
body.dribbble-shot .post-header, body.flickr-photo .post-header {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
body.dribbble-shot .post-header h1, body.flickr-photo .post-header h1 {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 1em;
}
/*

    *

    *

    * Flickr Responsive Profile

    *

    *

    */

body.flickr-photo .sidebar {
    padding: 0;
}
body.flickr-photo .jplnav {
    margin-left: 0;
}
body.flickr-photo .jplnav li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile {
    padding: 0;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile .avatar-wrapper {
    float: none;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
body.flickr-photo .profile-about {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
.profile .profile-about {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Etsy Overrides

*

*

*/

body.etsy-listing .post-header {
    padding: 400px 0 0 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
body.etsy-listing .post-header h1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 10% 20px 10%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.3em !important;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
body.etsy-listing .post-header p.Lrg {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1em !important;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
}



/* Landscape phones and down */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
.main-content-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 200px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Section Navigation

*

*

*/

.sections a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 4px 4px 0;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: User Profile Navigation

*

*

*/

.expand-profile {
    right: 30%;
}
.profile .twitter-handle a {
    right: 50%;
}
/*

*

*

* Responsive: Generic Font Treatments

*

*

*/

.Lrg {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.Med {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.Sml {
    font-size: 14px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to go in your head element

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I prefer this from below as the initial-scale is good to set imo

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Add this within your head tag.

Comment: [Please don't use maximum-scale in viewport tags](http://alwaystwisted.com/post.php?s=2013-01-10-dont-do-this-in-responsive-web-development)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```